# MongoDB 3.4 Upsert not inserting

Tags: java, mongodb, upsert, mongo-shell

Trying the following in the Mongo shell (and tried it in Java) to update or insert a document. The filter should return false but I am expected the document to be created due to upsert = true

```
db.eventLogs.updateOne(
                      {monthid:"062017", elementid:123456},
                      {$push: {
                               events: {sensor1:"sensor1 value",
                                        sensor2:"sensor2 value"
                                       } 
                              } 
                      }, 
                      {Upsert:true} )
```

The statement is acknowledged but nothing is inserted into the collection even though Upsert = true.

I'm clearly being an idiot so can someone put me out of my misery?

Java version...

```
 Bson filter = Document.parse(argFilterJson);
 Bson operations = Document.parse(argOperationsJson);
 UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);

 return this.getCollection(argDBName, argCollectionName).updateOne(filter, operations, options);
```

The values of argFilterJson and argOperationsJson are exactly as per the shell.

Comment: Try changing the `Upsert` to `upsert`

Comment: As suggested by Veeram, it should be "upsert" and not "Upsert" for the Mongo Shell however it still doesn't work when using the Java driver. I've added the Java code above.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, after restarting my MongoDB server, the Java code has started to work as expected.